# metodo enumerate() - TypeError: Can only concatenate str (not "Int") to str

Tags: python, string, tkinter, interfaz-gráfica, enum

Llevo un par de días haciendo un ahorcado con los pocos conocimientos adquiridos de python. Primero lo hice para que el programa funcionase por consola y ahí todo correcto. Ahora lo he querido introducir en una interfaz gráfica pero tengo un problema que no consigo solucionar.

```
from tkinter import *
import random


root = Tk()
root.title("Ahorcado")
root.geometry("400x200")
root.resizable(0,0)

# Creamos la lista con las palabras

lista_palabras = [
"Eructo",
"Minimalista",
"Aprecio",
"Taxidermista",
"Acaparador",
"Murcielago",
"Coronavirus",
"Apreciacion",
"Encuadernar",
"Proctologo",
]

 # Creamos las variables
 palabra_oculta=StringVar()
 errores = StringVar()
 palabra = lista_palabras[random.randint(0,len(lista_palabras))]
 palabra_oculta2 = ["_"]*len(palabra)
 palabra_oculta.set(palabra_oculta2)
 letras_añadidas=""
 numero_errores = 0
 contador = 0

 def introduce_letra():
     global letras_añadidas
     global numero_errores
     global contador

     if letra.get() == "":
         errores.set("No hay letra")
     elif len(letra.get()) > 1:
         errores.set("Se ha introducido mas de 1 letra")
     else:
         if letra.get() in letras_añadidas:
             errores.set("La letra introducida ya existe")
             numero_errores+=1
         else:
             letras_añadidas+=letra.get()
             for i, l in enumerate(palabra): **<===** ERROR
                 if letra.get() == l:
                     palabra_oculta2[i]=letra.get()
                     palabra_oculta.set(palabra_oculta2)
                     contador+=1
             if contador>0:
                 errores.set("Se han encontrado {} {}".format(contador, letra.get()))
             else:
                 errores.set("No se han encontrado {} en la palabra".format(letra.get()))


 def introduce_palabra():
     pass

  # Label con la palabra oculta
 label_palabra_oculta = Label(root, textvariable=palabra_oculta, font=("Consolas", 12))
 label_palabra_oculta.pack(anchor=CENTER)
 label_palabra_oculta.config(padx=15, pady=15)

  # Frame inferior con los widgets
 frame_inferior = Frame(root, width=400, height=110)
 frame_inferior.pack(side="bottom")
 frame_inferior.pack_propagate(0)
 frame_inferior.config(bg="seashell3")

  # Label de introducción de letra
 label_letra = Label(frame_inferior, text="Introduce una letra", font=("Consolas", 10))
 label_letra.pack(anchor="nw")
 label_letra.config(pady=5, padx=5)
 label_letra.config(bg="seashell3")

  # Label de introducción de palabra
 label_palabra = Label(frame_inferior, text="Introduce la palabra", font=("Consolas", 10))
 label_palabra.place(x=246, y=0)
 label_palabra.config(padx=5, pady=5)
 label_palabra.config(bg="seashell3")

  # Entry de introducción de letra
 letra = Entry(frame_inferior, width=1, font=("Consolas", 10))
 letra.place(x=65, y=25)

  # Boton de introducción de letra
 boton_letra= Button(frame_inferior,text="Aceptar", font=("Consolas", 8), command=introduce_letra)
 boton_letra.place(x=45, y=50)

  # Entry de introducción de palabra
 palabra = Entry(frame_inferior, width=16, font=("Consolas", 10))
 palabra.place(x=265,y=25)

  # Boton de introducción de palabra
 boton_letra= Button(frame_inferior,text="Aceptar", font=("Consolas", 8))
 boton_letra.place(x=300, y=50)

  # Label contador de Errores
 label_errores = Label(frame_inferior, textvariable=errores, font=("Consolas",10 ))
 label_errores.pack(side="bottom", fill="both")
 label_errores.config(bg="seashell4", padx=1, pady=1)


 root.mainloop()
```

En la linea del enumerate() me da el siguiente error:

**TypeError: can only concatenate str (not "int") to str**

No se como recorrer la palabra aleatoria generada de tal forma que cada vez que se introduzca la letra se modifique la palabra oculta.

Muchas gracias de antemano!

Comment: estás concatenando una string con un int. Debes convertir el int a str con `str()` para que sea válido

Answer (score 0):

Nunca antes había usado tkinter, sin embargo, la solución a tu pregunta es únicamente añadir `str()` en tu `enumerate()`, es decir: `for i, l in enumerate(str(palabra)):`. Y con eso se soluciona el error por el que has decidido hacer esta pregunta, sin embargo, aún tienes varios errores lógicos. Revisa eso, y buena suerte en tu aprendizaje.